# CSS Issues / HTML Issues Working fine in local host

Tags: html, css

I have made a website and my CSS is working fine on my localhost but when I upload it to my web server it bugs out.

Here is the bugged out version: http://gayming.xyz/about/

Here is what it is supposed to look like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8s0L.png

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: It does include what's not working. I've added a screenshot of how it should look

Comment: A screenshot doesn't help people who can't see the image. Also "shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself" means the code needs to be here in the question, not just a link to a 3rd party location.

Comment: so if I paste my code in here it will be fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using both flexbox and float. Take `v-align` class out of your left and right boxes and it should take you closer to what you want.